# Nginx - alias for directory but return 403 for /

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Here's a part of my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  location /f/ {
     autoindex on;
     alias /ftp/;
   }
}
```

When I go to `www.mywebsite.com/f/foo.txt`, it returns the file if it exists in `/ftp/` or a 404 error if it doesn't.

When I go to `www.mywebsite.com/f/`, it lists all files in `/ftp/` directory.

Would there be any way return a 403 error instead of listing all files?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I seem impolite, seems like stackoverflow has removed the "Hello" I had wrote at the begining...

Comment: Found out `autoindex: on;` was doing this